# zipkin error Error creating bean with name 'webMvcMetricsFilter' defined in class path resource

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, zipkin

When I tried to integrate zipkin. It threw this error

```
Error Msg:Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcMetricsFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/web/servlet/WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'webMvcMetricsFilter' parameter 0;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'prometheusMeterRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/prometheus/PrometheusMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed;
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'zipkin2.server.internal.ZipkinServerConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'httpQuery';
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'zipkin2.server.internal.ZipkinQueryApiV2': Bean instantiation via constructor failed;
nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: zipkin2/internal/Buffer$Writer
```

version:

- Springboot 2.2.4
- SpringCloud Hoxton.SR1 (sleuth: 2.2.1)
- zipkin 2.19.9

```
@EnableZipkinServer
@SpringBootApplication
public class C4ZipkinApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(C4ZipkinApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
   <artifactId>zipkin-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
   <groupId>io.zipkin.java</groupId>
   <artifactId>zipkin-autoconfigure-ui</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Hi, did you solve the problem? I also have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your application starts in Tomcat Server but Zipkin use another server but i dont know that name , i include this code to spring boot starter web dependecy for ignore tomcat server

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

This worked for me try it

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a config server, remember to run it before running your microservices.