# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcMetricsFilter' defined in class

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-actuator

Error in console:

```
2023-02-24 09:37:19.082 ERROR 41612 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'webMvcMetricsFilter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/web/servlet/WebMvcMetricsAutoConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'webMvcMetricsFilter' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'simpleMeterRegistry' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/export/simple/SimpleMetricsExportAutoConfiguration.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourcePoolMetadataMeterBinder' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/metrics/jdbc/DataSourcePoolMetricsAutoConfiguration$DataSourcePoolMetadataMetricsConfiguration.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'dataSourcePoolMetadataMeterBinder' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
2023-02-24 09:37:19.349  INFO 41612 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2023-02-24 09:37:19.705  WARN 41612 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2023-02-24 09:37:19.837  INFO 41612 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-02-24 09:37:19.970 ERROR 41612 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************
```

Description:

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.
```

Reason: *Failed to determine a suitable driver class*

Action:

Consider the following:

```
If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

POM.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.8</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.car</groupId>
    <artifactId>car</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>car-demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-actuator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/cardb
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-wait=20000
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-active=50
spring.datasource.tomcat.max-idle=20
spring.datasource.tomcat.min-idle=15
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings = false
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE
```

main function
application.java

```
package com.car;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class CarDemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(CarDemoApplication.class, args);
        System.out.println("hello from car");
    }
}
```

I tried removing some of  the dependencies, but it didnt worked for me [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60023762/zipkin-error-error-creating-bean-with-name-webmvcmetricsfilter-defined-in-clas).

Comment: I think the property should have value: `spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work, i think theres is no need of writing cj. as it says the new driver class is automatically registered via SPI

Comment: error occurs after i add actuator dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the following code:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

in dependencies in maven file (pom.xml) Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the `spring-data jpa dependency` as a transient dependency. I resolved this problem by excluding the `jpa depndency`.

If you are not trying to connect your application to any database, then this will work.